# Port 80 is not available outside localhost

Tags: networking, apache-httpd, access-point

I have a wifi-access point at wlan0 ip 10.42.0.1 . At the same machine there is httpd runnig locally, and when i access it from local browser by 10.42.0.1 - i can see webpage perfectly fine. When i do on that machine nmap i can see port 80 is open.

But when i connect to that access point from another machine, even i can ping 10.42.0.1 fine - wget or browser gives me connction refused, as well as nmap shows no 80 open.

what i have done already:

1. In httpd.conf i have added Listen 10.42.0.1:80
2. I have added ip table rule iptables -I INPUT -p TCP --dport 80 -j ACCEPT
3. I checked with tcpdump port 80 - and actually can see traffic comes in when i am trying to access web page.

What esle can i do to solve the problem?

UPD ip table input rule is there:

```
Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT 0 packets, 0 bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         
   14  1524 ACCEPT     tcp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            tcp dpt:80
    0     0 LOG        tcp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            tcp dpt:80 LOG flags 0 level 4
    2    88 ACCEPT     tcp  --  wlan0  *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            tcp dpt:80 /* # Anaconda Repo # */
    0     0 ACCEPT     tcp  --  eth0   *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            tcp dpt:80 /* # Anaconda Repo # */
82027   81M LIBVIRT_INP  all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0
```

Comment: Do you have any other rules that could be rejecting the traffic before your accept rule? `iptables -L -n -v`

Comment: @PaulBurrows i have updated question with input rules that i got with this command

Comment: That is strange. I would try to turn off iptables completely and try it again.
If it will work, you can be sure, the problems is with the firewall.

Comment: @JohnRonald doesn't help. May be the fact that i have access point on the same ip/interface matters? Somthing like the interface is used to share wifi and can't accept incoming connection

Comment: To avoid a lot of further questions, can you complete your question with the output of this? `ip -br link; ip -br address; ip route` and `iptables-save -c` which has a way better usable output than `iptables -L` . Also what is the IP address of the client trying and failing to reach the web server?

Comment: @A.B thanks a lot!, that output really helped. After one more round of checks found out that even iptables service is off, there is firewalld , that blocks connections. Will search now about that service.

Comment: So you're not asking the question anymore? If you do please edit it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It was the firewalld service that was blocking ports.